# Could not find a valid titanium module

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I'm new on Appcelerator Titanium. I have old version a project. I want to upgrade my project, but I get an error. I used some method but didnt work. How can I solve this problem?

> [INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=ti.map version=3.1.2
> platform=iphone deploy-type=development
> path=/Users/krt/Library/Application
> Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/ti.map/3.1.2
>
> [WARN] :   Could not find
> a valid Titanium module id=com.adr.module version=latest
> platform=iphone deploy-type=development
>
> [INFO] :   Found Titanium
> module id=ti.cloud version=3.2.10 platform=commonjs
> deploy-type=development path=/Users/krt/Library/Application
> Support/Titanium/modules/commonjs/ti.cloud/3.2.10
>
> [ERROR] :  Could not
>
> find all required Titanium Modules:
>
> [ERROR] :     id: com.adr.module
> version: latest    platform: iphone    deploy-type: development

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to compile your project but you don't have com.adr.module on your computer.

If this module functionality is required for your application than you have to add this module to you Appcelerator Studio or remove the functionality.

Comment: I import com.adr.module to the project.

Comment: Appcelerator Studio says it couldn't find your module.
If you imported that module check if it available in tiapp.xml. If is available check if it is added for iOS (I see you try to compile for iPhone). If everything is fine try to delete module from project and then add it again. Also try to clean project (there is such option in menu) before running it.
The other thing I have in mind is that maybe your module is old and won't compile with actual SDK. But I think in such case error would be slightly different.